# How to deal with country specific questions - tags for countries

Tags: discussion

SOme questions may be USA specifici (e.g., freedom of information act)

We should have a system of tags for countries.

Comment: I think the tags [tag:us], [tag:germany] are enough. I don't see what else could improve the process. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: should we stick with some country codes? or any ideas on use us vs usa vs united-states

Comment: @Vince : the term 'us' has multiple definitions.  (eg, the one like 'we') ... it should be changed to 'united-states' or 'usa', or something less bad. ... and then I read your comment below, so nevermind

Comment: I second Joe's suggestion for USA instead of US

Answer (score 5):

My instinct is to use country codes, just because there will probably be cases where a common name is ambiguous. It would be kind of neato if the country tags could have little flag icons, like some of the vendor-specific Stack Overflow tags have.

But I also think that most questions will be country specific.

Comment: so just curious... how, as a community, do we close discussion on questions like this and move on? I haven't been particularly involved in meta boards for other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, there should be some sort of systematic naming of country tags, ie "Based on the ISO system for countries", or "Based on the Travel.SE tags for countries".

Answer (score 1):

The exact format is indeed quite a problem.

I think there is no definitive answer, because there will always be new debates, up to discussing whether Palestine is a country, or should we say a territory, ... And this is not the point of OpenData.SE.

There are quite some such questions on Travel.SE, look at [one of them](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/730/please-rename-the-georgia-country-tag) that raises the issue of regions and countries sharing the same name.

I think we should simply stick to simplicity and clear use. I would say, let's keep the simple English country names: [germany](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany), [india](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india). For the US, the only reason it is so is that the first few questions included the tag [us](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us), before anyone took action. But I suggest, once someone has enough privilege to create synonyms, to replace it by [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa).

Answer (score 1):

The problem already occured on StackOverflow, and with much more severe form. There are group of products grouped in product, and they are versioned, for example JSF is a group of technologies including PrimeFaces, RichFaces, IceFaces, each of them have version. So should the question tagged with [primefaces-3.4](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primefaces-3.4) be automatically assigned to category [primefaces](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) and category [jsf](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsf)? But such feature was not implemented. See the details for example here: [A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)

If such feature was not implemented for StackOverflow, it won't be implemented for any other site as well. So you should use 5 available tags wisely.

As a rule of the thumb, I'll just tag the question with the most appropriate region, for example [germany](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) for questions specific about Germany, and [europe](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) for questions targeting multiple countries. Where the question is about Germany, but the domain is related to European Union and the database could be managed by EU, I'd add [eu](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) tag then. If the question is targeting German-speaking countries, I'd use 3 country tags. For questions targeting French-speaking countries of Africa, I'd simply use [africa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/africa) tag.